# Switch between object properties in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

**QUESTION**

I would like to know  **how can I switch between object properties** in Vue.js.

Here is a visual example:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        myObject:{
            one: 'lorem',
            two: 'ipsum'
        }
    }
});
```

I want to be able to change from `{{ myObject.one }}` to `{{ myObject.two }}`, on the same place in the html, but I don't know if it's possible.

**I have tried two solutions**, but they require more code and resources:

1) repeat the html for every object property and use [v-show](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-show)

2) use only one property and change its content via ajax

Is there a better way that not requires multiple ajax calls or repeating html?

**CONTEXT**

I want to make a multilingual app, where the content changes clicking in a button. The code looks like this:

```
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ title.en }}</h1>
    <div>

    <script>
        var vm = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data:{
                title:{
                    en: 'Hello',
                    es: 'Hola'
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I want to switch from `{{ title.en }}` to `{{ title.es }}`

Thank you very much

Comment: Don't you need i18n here? https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n

Comment: Thank you for the plugin @rmagnum2002!
The problem is that the data structure has to be this one title{en:'hello',es:'hola'} instead of es:{title:'hola'},en:{title:'hello'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `lang` variable to something like `'en'` and use `title[lang]`. This will be the same as calling `title.en`.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    lang: 'en',
    title: {
      en: 'Hello',
      es: 'Hola'
    }
  }
});

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li @click="lang = 'en'">English</li>
    <li @click="lang = 'es'">Spanish</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>{{ title[lang] }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.